# TableView not updating contentInSet property properly when Device Orientation Changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, swift

Specifically on iPhone displays newer than the iPhone 4S, my tableView does not adjust properly in landscape mode.

Originally I had thought autolayout was causing the issue, but it turns out the contentInSet property of my tableView is not adjusting properly whenever the device orientation changes. The bottom cell (last cell) in my tableView is partially cut off because the scroll cannot reach far enough. The only way I can solve this problem is horribly hacky which is to manually adjust the `contentInSet.bottom` whenever orientation changes (on certain devices) like so:

```
override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval)
    {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        if (toInterfaceOrientation.isLandscape == true) {
            self.tableView.contentInset.bottom = self.tableView.contentInset.bottom + 50
        }

    }
```

That would be the general idea, but it is an unfinished implementation because I feel like this doesn't solve the real bug occurring here. It would also prevent my code from being 'future-proof'. Can somebody please help me out?

Note: This is running on XCode 6 Beta 5 (newest beta version).